# Can I use Reverse Proxy between static hosted and dynamic hosted sites in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy

We are migrating a legacy web application feature by feature and require all functionality to be available to logged in users during the migration.

This means that that the functionality yet to be migrated would sit in something like

`old.mydomain.com/orders` or `www.mydomain.com/old/orders`

while migrated features sit on the primary domain addresses

`www.mydomain.com/login` and `www.mydomain.com/invoices`.

All paths should appear to the user as if they are hosted together e.g.

`www.mydomain.com/orders`

and login status should be remembered across new and old sites.

The new site will be statically hosted on S3 and served through CloudFront. Authentication will be migrated to Cognito.

The old site will be hosted on an EC2 Windows instance using IIS.

We are currently thinking of adding something like NginX to manage the routing between applications but there is some discussion within the team whether this is overkill or even the right solution.

My questions are

1. Will this solution do what we need it to?
2. Is there a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the new site is on S3 and hosted through CloudFront, I would point the root domain to CloudFront and configure multiple origins (S3, and the Windows server) for the CloudFront distribution. Configure CloudFront to route the specific paths to the desired backend, and update those routes in CloudFront as you migrate.